# boost::any_cast and std::optional's

Tags: c++, option-type, boost-any

I use `boost::any`, and have some function which retrieves such a value, but may fail, so it actually returns `std::optional<boost::any>` (well, for now it's `std::experimental::optional`). Now, without the optional, I get my typed value back using `boost::any_cast(my_retrieved_any)`. To handle the optional case, I've written the following:

```
template<typename ValueType>
inline const optional<ValueType> boost_any_cast(const optional<boost::any>& operand)
{
    return operand ? boost::any_cast(operand.value()) : nullopt;
}
```

But this doesn't compile (with Boost 1.58 and GCC 4.9.3). I get:

```
/file.cpp(12): error: no instance of overloaded function "boost::any_cast" 
matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const boost::any)
```

How is this possible? Why is the argument not `boost::any&` ? I tried setting a variable to operand.value(), then passing that to the any_cast - but that didn't seem to help either:

```
template<typename ValueType>
inline const optional<ValueType> boost_any_cast(const optional<boost::any>& operand)
{
    if (operand) {
        boost::any x(operand.value());
        return boost::any_cast(x);
    }
    return nullopt;
}
```

This gets me:

```
/file.cpp(13): error: no instance of overloaded function "boost::any_cast"
 matches the argument list
            argument types are: (boost::any)
```

There must be something I'm not taking into account regarding `boost::any`'s... what is it? And how can I fix this "casting" operation?

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper: See edit.

Comment: What type is that `list`? Could you provide code calling the `boost_any_cast()`?

Comment: @JanKorous: There isn't any list in the code, it's the function's "argument list". And the code calling boost_any cast() is `auto x = boost_any_cast<unsigned>(function_returning_optional_boost_any())`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`boost::any_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any/reference.html) requires a template argument;

```
template<typename T> T any_cast(const any &);
```

From you code snippet, you probably need;

```
boost::any_cast<ValueType>(operand.value())
```